# Is there a react signature pad which allows both type characters or draw signature

Tags: reactjs, signaturepad

I want to use digital signature for my react web application.I came across react signature_pad but it has the functionality to draw the signature alone.
Is there any react library which allows to type the name in a fancy font as well as provides an option to draw the signature

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, currently there isn't a library can do this for you. But a workaround is that you may consider **Cursive Writing Fonts** to change fonts into signature for your users.

Example of a list of signature fonts can be found at:
https://www.1001fonts.com/cursive-fonts.html

You can dynamically change fonts to show different signature style for your users based on the name they provide. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I have created a canvas and created code from scratch